# face-recognition gives an error but i dont know what to do

Tags: numpy, face-recognition, opencv, dlib, python

when i start my program with face-recognition it gaves me an error and i dont now how to fix it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\smera\Desktop\face.py", line 29, in <module>
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\smera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 214, in face_encodings
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\smera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 214, in <listcomp>
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: compute_face_descriptor(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], face: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
    2. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
    3. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], faces: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors
    4. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], batch_faces: List[_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections], num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectorss
    5. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors
```

Invoked with:

```
<_dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1 object at 0x000001B0A21026B0>, array([[[161, 151, 143],
        [158, 151, 142],
        [157, 150, 147],
        ...,
        [149, 138, 115],
        [149, 136, 130],
        [147, 134, 135]],

       [[158, 149, 140],
        [159, 150, 142],
        [160, 150, 142],
        ...,
        [148, 138, 128],
        [150, 138, 129],
        [149, 137, 127]],

       [[159, 151, 140],
        [157, 150, 129],
        [156, 149, 137],
        ...,
        [148, 139, 127],
        [149, 139, 131],
        [149, 139, 131]],

       ...,

       [[123,  98,  59],
        [119, 101,  60],
        [118, 101,  64],
        ...,
        [ 55,  73, 100],
        [ 72,  82,  92],
        [ 83,  93,  97]],

       [[119,  98,  67],
        [122,  99,  72],
        [121,  98,  73],
        ...,
        [ 67,  84, 101],
        [ 97, 110, 116],
        [ 97, 110, 114]],

       [[112, 100,  69],
        [116, 100,  71],
        [124,  98,  81],
        ...,
        [ 70,  80,  86],
        [103, 109,  98],
        [106, 111, 107]]], dtype=uint8), <_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection object at 0x000001B0A3FAC170>, 1
```

i triw asking chat gpt but it still give me this error

here the code:
`

```
import face_recognition
import cv2

known_faces = []
known_labels = []

known_faces.append(face_recognition.load_image_file("file.jpg"))
known_labels.append("file")

known_faces.append(face_recognition.load_image_file("file.jpg"))
known_labels.append("file")
known_encodings = []
for face in known_faces:
    face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face)[0]
    known_encodings.append(face_encoding)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
    rgb_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    
    # Verifica se sono stati rilevati volti
    if len(face_locations) > 0:
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)
    
        for face_encoding, face_location in zip(face_encodings, face_locations):
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_encodings, face_encoding)
            name = "Sconosciuto"

            if True in matches:
                first_match_index = matches.index(True)
                name = known_labels[first_match_index]

            top, right, bottom, left = face_location
            top *= 4
            right *= 4
            bottom *= 4
            left *= 4

            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

Comment: I don't know anything about this face-recognition software, but I will suggest rereading the documentation for `face_recognition.face_encodings`, paying close attention to what kinds of arguments it takes.  And then review the arguments that you pass to it.  The error says one or more is of the wrong type.